# React.render to virtual DOM (instead of rendering to real DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

So my question is this: In React, there is a way to do this:

```
var renderedComponent = React.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

...and React with render the element `MyComponent` to a component, and mount it at `document.body`.

If I don't want to mount my component on the real DOM, then I do:

```
var renderedString = React.renderToString(<MyComponent />);
```

However, if I want to render the element to a component, and **not** mount it to any real DOM node, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Basically I want to do:

```
var renderedComponent = React.renderToVirtual(<MyComponent />)
// do some stuff with the component
renderedComponent.doSomeStuff(...)
// now we're done, render it to a string
var renderedString = React.componentToString(renderedComponent)
```

So basically the two methods I can't seem to find are: 1) `renderToVirtual`, and `componentToString`.  Any pointers on how to achieve this?  Thanks!

Comment: In the React Test Utils there is [renderIntoDocument](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument) which seems to do exactly the type of thing you require.

Comment: @DavinTryon - the documentation for that method says "This function requires a DOM."  When calling it in my code (server-side), it throws an error that "document is not defined", as expected.  If only it existed for server-side!

Comment: It looks like this question essentially boils down to "I want to perform some logic after the component is created but before it is rendered to the DOM".  Is this an accurate representation of what you're looking for?

Comment: @MichaelParker yes; I am also calling React in this case on the server-side, so there is no browser DOM in existence